# Form_closing Form_resize EventHandlers

Tags: c#, .net

How to write just one code block for this two events ?
I would like to execute same code when user  minimize, resize or close form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Closing += (sender, e) => this.DoWork();
this.Resize += (sender, e) => this.DoWork();

private void DoWork()
{
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a method for the functionality and call the method from the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function for your common code and call it from whereever you want.

if you want to call it when the form is closed and resized write it as below:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                myfunction();
            }


            private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                myfunction();
            }

      private void myfunction()
            {
                //function code here
            }
```